# How to add a scheduler job after last job is over

Tags: python, apscheduler

I know that apscheduler was able to do schedule jobs with:

```
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(run, 'interval', seconds=60)
```

but now I want the next job started after last job is finished 1mins later, I wonder if it can be relized.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to attach an event listener to a job which gets called at job completion. https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html#scheduler-events

Within that listener, you can schedule the next job 60 seconds in the future.

Comment: I think maybe this can be realize with setting timeout of schedule job. Once the previous job run more than 1min, it should be terminated and the next job started

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you can try using the sleep() between your two jobs or as a part of the first job definition:

```
from time import sleep 
sleep(60)
```